# Comunicación de componentes en Angular

Tags: angular

Hola me gustaría mandar una función de un componente hijo a el padre

- Padre HTML

```html
<select name="cat" (change)="change($event.target.value)">
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="business">Negocios</option>
    <option value="entertainment">Entretenimiento</option>
    <option value="health">Salud</option>
    <option value="science">Ciencia</option>
    <option value="sports">Deportes</option>
    <option value="technology">Tecnología</option>
</select>
```

TS Padre

```
public change(value): void {
    // funcionHija(value);
}
```

Funcion Hija

```
listData(value = 'general'): void {
    this._noticiaService.getDataApi(value).subscribe(
        resp => this.noticias = resp
    );
}
```

Comment: Si proporcionas una mejor explicación de lo que **esperas resolver**, un  poco de **código** extra de tu trabajo actual y detalles de lo que supones causa el problema **concreto**, entonces podemos ayudarte, de otra forma tu pregunta me parece algo muy general que puedes consultar en la documentación oficial sin problema.

Comment: Con enviar una funcion a que te refieres?

Comment: Tengo esta función: listData(value = 'general'): void {
    this._noticiaService.getDataApi(value).subscribe(
      resp => this.noticias = resp
    );
  }  y la quiero ocupar asi tal cual en un componente padre

Comment: reescribe el llamado de esa funcion en el padre, o hay algun evento en especifico que el hijo necesite enviarle al padre?

Comment: acabo de poner el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puede hacer es utilizar [`@ViewChield`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) para hacer referencia al componente hijo y con este llamar al metodo. Ejemplo:

**app.ts**
`

```
export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Angular';
      // Desde el componente padre hace la referencia al unico `HijoComponent` y esta queda en la variable `hijo
      @ViewChild(HijoComponent) hijo: HijoComponent;

      // Este metodo llamara al metodo del componente hijo
      cambiarTextoHijo(): void {
            this.hijo.cambiarTextoPorOtro();
      }

}
```

**app.html**

```
<app-hijo></app-hijo>
<button (click)="cambiarTextoHijo()">Cambiar Texto</button>
```

**hijo.ts**

```
export class HijoComponent {

      texto: String = "Cuando de click en el boton el texto cambiara";

      // Metodo que sera llamado desde el app.component.ts
      cambiarTextoPorOtro(){
            this.texto = "Este metodo fue llamado desde el padre";
      }

}
```

**hijo.html**

```
<p>{{ texto }}</p>
```

De igual manera te dejo el metodo implementado en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyf5kg)